# Auth::user()->username and similar are very slow

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I am having a werid issue. My Laravel 5 application is very slow, it take 1-3 seconds to completely load, that is something that is not tolerable.

After hours of debugging, I found out that the issue is `Auth::user()`, more specifically when you try to access something like `Auth::user()->username`.

What I noticed: `Auth::user()->id` is blazing fast, while `Auth::user()->username` takes 1-3 seconds. It does also not to appear to have something todo with the mySQL server, as the exact same queries are being executed, no matter if I use `->id` or `->username`.

It is not only that slow when using `->username` but it appears to be that slow for alsmost everything besides `->id`, also when accessing roles like `Auth::user()->roles`.

In case it matters, I am using Entrust for the permission/role management.

User Model:

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Zizaco\Entrust\Traits\EntrustUserTrait;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;

class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract
{
    use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword, EntrustUserTrait, SoftDeletes;

    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $guarded = ['id'];
    protected $fillable = ['username', 'email', 'activation_code'];
    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    public function personalData()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(UserPersonalData::class);
    }

    public function banned()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(BanUser::class);
    }

}
```

Even if I remove the Entrust Service Provider and therefore also the EntrustUserTrait, it is still as slow as before.

`SHOW CREATE TABLE users` as requested

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
 `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `username` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `password` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `activated` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `activation_code` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `remember_token` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 `deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `users_username_unique` (`username`),
 UNIQUE KEY `users_email_unique` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Thanks!

Comment: Just a assumption, Can you try deleting all the files under session in your storage folder ?

Comment: Thanks, sadly that did not help.

Comment: Are you loading many classes inside your controller ?

Comment: Nevermind, even though it were'nt the sessions, removing the cached views did the trick. No idea why though. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, To makes the future readers helpful, you shall add it as your answer, If you need i will post it as answer with some helpful information too :)

Comment: Sadly I have to bring the question up again. Even though it is a lot faster when the debug mode is disabled (due to the caching), it is still slow as hell when caching is disabled, so something is wrong there. Regarding the controller question, no, not really, besides the question why it is not slowing down when using ->id. Thanks for any help!

Comment: I added a bounty, to encourage people to invest their time. Thank you!

Comment: Did you looked at the logs for any useful information ? Could you tell us more about your configuration ?

Comment: The logs are fine, no errors there. Sure, please let me know what exactly you would like to know. Thanks!

Comment: I added some more informaiton. Please let me know if you need something specific. Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just use xdebug's profiler to see what's taking up so much time?

Comment: I already tried a couple of profilers but all of them reported nothing to work with. For example the laravel debugbar shows a loding time of 140ms, the browser however had to wait for 2,5 seconds according to the debug tools in Chrome and firefox. Is xdebug going to change anything about that? Never used it.

Comment: You'd be able to see what function calls take up most of the request time. Anyway, if debug toolbar is showing 140ms then that's more or less what PHP needed to process the request. What do you mean by "browser had to wait for 2.5 seconds?" Did the whole request take 2.5 seconds? You should be able to see how much of that time was spent connecting, receiving data etc.

Comment: I configured xdebug, I however don't know where I should not set a breakpoint to properly debug it. FireFox shows a "wait" time of 2.5 seconds.

Comment: http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler

Comment: I tried to render the view into a variable and then return the view in the next line. I set the breakpoint to the return. Now if i load the page, it will get to the breakpoint very fast, if I then press the resume button it will take about 2 seconds before the page is loading peoperly. Something is messed up there.. And btw, I am using xdebug with PHpStorm

Comment: Alright, xdebug created 3 of those files aftter 1 page reload. Could you please guide me on what I now need to search for? Thanks!

Comment: Okay, it looks like that the HTTP Kernel, more specifically the Pipeline is the issue as it takes about 1.6 seconds. I do however still need helpt o answer the question "why?". THanks!

Comment: How many "users" are there?

Comment: You don't think it is a MySQL issue, but please show us `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for that Laravel generates for `Auth::user`.  There may be something subtle going on here.

Comment: There is 1 user. Going through the whole pipeline stack boils down to 2 "classes" that load quite long. First of all the view render method, and the laravel debugbar. When I do the same with the ->id version, it does not take that long for both of these.

Comment: SHOW CREATE TABLE users has been added.

Comment: Just wondering have you tried running this code on a different machine or vm or something? Just wondering if it is something that is able to be reproduced.

Comment: Yes, even on my server it is as slow as it is on the local machine.

Comment: Have you for fun tried to install a fresh Laravel 5,x installation and see if you still have the same problem on the same environment? This sound like you have a conflict between laravel authorization and entrust even thus you did not added to the model if you let me know please

Comment: No, cause a simple clean install would not be related to my full application anymore. I also tried removing entrust, that did not change anything.

Comment: Is there any improve if you remove `personalData()` and `banned()` from the model?

Comment: Sadly not :( I think I have to do a clean install and slowl migrate everthing over until the issue occurres again :/

Comment: I wonder how the query to retrieve `->id` is the same as the one to retrieve `->name`. What makes you think so? Enable general mysql logs for the time of the queries and check what's really executed. Also, you could monitor the performance views to make sure of how long is spent on what

Comment: Because I select the whole user already when he is signing in, so that can't be the reaosn either.

Comment: You do not know that.

Comment: Yes I do, due to profiling plugins.

Answer (score 3):

Use xdebug to generate a profile of the execution. Then download that file and open it in Wincachegrind or Kcachegrind (depending on what OS you're running on your desktop)

In those programs you can drill down and see what's taking the extra time by double-clicking and looking at the columns to see how much time something has taken.

Answer (score 1):

Use method instead of Facade.

```
Use:
auth()->user()->username. 

Avoid use of:
Auth::user()->username.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a cache technology if you have big data and performance issue linking this,  like **memcache** table!

Comment: Thanks, but that's like putting 10 fire extinguishers near a frequently overheating place, instead of making sure that is does not overheat.

Answer (score 0):

The Auth facade returns an object of class Illuminate\Auth\Guard, normally it it caches the entire object you request.

Could it be that somewhere in your application the facade has been overwritten extended to a version that only caches the id instead of all the properties?

You might want to make the inital query for the user into `User::with('personalData','banned')` in your inital load so it will fetch all your relevant data.

Basically make sure all your fields get eager loaded on the first query for the user.

It's very strange only the user id is loaded, it's as if your user object gets instantiated with the id, but doesn't execute the query till you request it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Regarding the "overwritten" part, do you mean if I extended the Illuminate\Auth\Guard class somewhere?

Comment: If I search for ```extends Illuminate\Auth\Guard```or ```extends \Guard``` it won't find anything

Comment: Okay, then it might be worth your while to extend it yourself and modify it to your needs. here is a tutorial how to extend the auth driver. it's for laravel 4, but I don't think much has changed conceptually. http://toddish.co.uk/blog/creating-a-custom-laravel-4-auth-driver/

Comment: Not sure what "my needs" are. Could you please let me know on what I should aim for? Thanks!

Comment: Well, your needs are: When user is requested, eager load ALL fields and relations in one query and have it cached by the User facade. So extends the the auth to include a user object that when requested loads all the things you need once. That way only one query is done every fo the user object and for the rest it just resides in memory. By extending it  you can make sure all the data is request you specifically need.

Comment: Oh okay, so Laravel is smart enough to know that this data is already available and therefore won't request it again?

Comment: yes. basically is the Auth::user() object a singleton. But it only gets populated on first request. and depending on how your stuff is setup only certain fields will get requested by query on moment of request. By making it eager loading you force one request. to get all data in one fell swoop instead of bits and bops one at a time(which is more expensive ofc.

Comment: Not sure if this is indeed the issue, did you saw that I wrote that it is executing the exact same queries, no matter if I use ->id or ->username? Besides that, I should not take 2-3 seconds anyways.